# Administrador django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Un saludo para todos.

Quisiera saber si existe forma de crear en un solo formulario del administrador de `Django`, dos objetos relacionados uno a uno.
A continuación el código que estoy usando.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Persona(RegistroTiempo):
    tipo_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, choices=TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_CHOICES)
    identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,
                                      verbose_name=_('identificación'))


class PersonaNatural(RegistroTiempo):
    persona = models.OneToOneField(Persona, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('nombres'))
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('apellidos'))
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('fecha de nacimiento'))
    lugar_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('lugar de nacimiento'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('pesona natural')
        verbose_name_plural = _('personas naturales')
        ordering = ['persona']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombres
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(PersonaNatural)
class PersonaNaturalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = ('Información Basica', {
        'fields': ('nombres', 'apellidos', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'lugar_nacimiento',
        )
    }),
    readonly_fields = ['fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion']
```

Quiero crear una instancia de `Persona` desde este formulario de `PersonaNatural` ¿Como lo podría hacer?.

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: El codigo que me recomendo @loki funciona pero si se usa de forma invertida las clases, es decir la clase `PersonaNatural` es la que debe usar el `inline`. De lo contrario genera el siguiente error. `<class 'aplicaciones.beneficiarios.admin.PersonaInline'>: (admin.E301) 'beneficiarios.Persona' has no GenericForeignKey.`

Comment: El aporte de @loki me fue de mucha ayuda, sin embargo tengo otro modelo llamado `PersonaJuridica` que también se relaciona de uno a uno con el modelo `Persona` y deseo hacer lo mismo con el administrador de este, pero teniendo en cuenta el comentario anterior solo puedo usar una vez el `admin.site.register(Persona, PersonaAdmin)` alguien sabe como puedo registrarlo 2 veces?

Answer (score 0):

Django proporciona un par de clases [Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline).
En `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.admin import GenericTabularInline

class PersonaInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Persona

class PersonaNaturalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(PersonaNatural, PersonaNaturalAdmin)
```

Puedes usar `GenericStackedInline` dependiendo del 'layout' que quieras.

Comment: Funciona pero si se usa de forma invertida las clases, es decir la clase `PersonaNatural` es la que debe usar el `inline`. De lo contrario genera el siguiente error. `<class 'aplicaciones.beneficiarios.admin.PersonaInline'>: (admin.E301) 'beneficiarios.Persona' has no GenericForeignKey.`